# GCP Apache Airflow - How to install Python package from a private repository and import on DAG?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a private repository. This repository has my common functions about my DAG. (for example: datetime validaters, response encoder function)  I want to import this repository's functions on my DAG file and I used [this link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private) to do it.

I created `pip.conf` file. this file's location is : `my-bucket-name/config/pip/pip.conf` and i added my private github repository in this file like this:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://<token>@github.com/my-private-github-repo.git
```

After this, i wanted to import this repository's functions on my dag file (for example: from common-repo import *) but i got  **'module not found'** error on my DAG. (and unfortunately in the cloud composer logs, I couldn't see any log showing that the private github repo has been installed.)

I've searched a lot but can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the private repo to the requirements in a [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator) like this:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

@task.virtualenv(
   task_id="virtualenv_python",
   requirements=["https://<token>@github.com/my-private-github-repo.git"],
                 system_site_packages=False
)

def callable_from_virtualenv():
   import your_private_module

   ..etc...


virtualenv_task = callable_from_virtualenv()
```

(Example ripped from [Airflow python operator example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.html))

In order to avoid hardcoding token / credential in the source code, you can use an Airflow variable just like this:

```py
from airflow.models import Variable

@task.virtualenv(
   task_id="virtualenv_python",
   requirements=[Variable.get("private_github_repo")],
                 system_site_packages=False
)
```

Comment: this was important to me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have GitHub registered as a *connection* and I didn't want to replicate the token as a *variable*.

So I opted for another approach, using f-strings.
I understand being more readable, but I don't know if this can make the solution less secure.

PS: *GITHUB* is the name of connection...

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook

# Get connection
conn = BaseHook.get_connection('GITHUB')

@task.virtualenv(
   task_id="virtualenv_python",
   requirements=[
          f'git+https://{conn.password}@github.com/my-org/my-private-github-repo.git'
   ],
   system_site_packages=False
)

def callable_from_virtualenv():
   import your_private_module

   ..etc...


virtualenv_task = callable_from_virtualenv()
```

And as an advantage, it is not necessary to add several variables (one for each private package!).

I also tried jinja (which would avoid the need to include BaseHook) but I didn't succeed...

> `git+https://{{ conn.GITHUB.password }}@github.com/my-org/my-private-github-repo.git`